# Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 - Remove Project dropdown in C# navigation bar?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I recently updated my Visual Studio 2013 to Update 2 RTM. Now for my C# files, the navigation bar has a new dropdown for *Projects*, instead of just having *Types* and *Members* like it used to. The *Projects* dropdown is taking up valuable screen real estate.

Is there a way to hide that *Project* dropdown in the navigation bar?

See [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/06/03/using-the-navigation-bar-vstiptool0026.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20zainnab%20%28Visual%20Studio%20Tips%20and%20Tricks%29) for a picture of what a navigation bar looks like.

**Update:** I added a picture of what my navigation bar looks like for a C# file.

[image: My C# Navigation Bar]

Comment: What the heck is a "navigation bar"?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch See my edit. Add link to show you what the navigation bar is.

Comment: in which scope are you seeing this? what type of file is selected?

Comment: @DanielA.White I believe the OP said that it was for C# files.

Comment: I also found it very confusing. The tooltip is "Use this dropdown to view and switch to other projects this file may belong to"
and I'm not even sure what even means. A file either belongs to a project or not, there's no 'may' about it. And given that this dropdown is shown when viewing a *file*, then how can I view another project and why would I switch to another project? Does it switch to it in Solution Explorer?

Comment: @stuartd I find it confusing too. More importantly, it's taking up valuable screen real estate. Now the Members dropdown is squished.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't think as things currently stand that you can disable it, but its name is apparently "Context Switcher".

According to [this MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/04/08/building-windows-phone-8-1-apps-in-html.aspx), it would appear to be a new feature intended to help you manage shared files in [Universal Apps](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/2-540).  I agree that it's confusing, and I'm not a big fan.

A thorough search of the VS options for anything related to "Navigation Bar", "Context Switcher", or "Universal Apps" comes up empty and there don't seem to be any extensions offering this capability either. As far as I know these would be the main avenues for configuration, so my conclusion is that we are stuck with it until the next VS update or until someone gets around to making an extension that can disable it.

If you prefer, you can disable the navigation bar entirely in "Tools > Options > Text Editor > All Languages > Navigation Bar" (or you can disable the bar on a language by language basis.)

**Update:** As of [Visual Studio 2013 Update 3](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2933779), you can drag and adjust the relative sizing of the 3 drop down lists in the navigation bar.

From a little local testing it looks like the sizing you set is shared between all files and solutions and it persists after closing and reopening visual studio.

I shrank the context switcher down to just the visible text, and it feels more well proportioned and closer to the classic Class and Member drop down layout.

Comment: I know it's hard to provide evidence that something *is not* possible but do you have any references to directly back up your statement that the dropdown can't be disabled? Otherwise it appears your are only giving an opinion instead of a fact-based answer.

Comment: Since it's so new, there isn't much information out there. I just wanted to share what little I could find, since it took me some digging to even figure out what to call it. I did a thorough search of VS options before posting and tried to qualify my answer as best I could to not sound too totalitarian.  As you suggest, it's nearly impossible to prove an impossibility.

Comment: What you found is very valuable as now we know what to call the actual dropdown. But for future reference, if you are not prepared to also provide an answer to the question, this information should be added as a comment to the original question. Unfortunately, SO requires 50 rep before you can add comments so in your case, you have no way to contribute such information unless it is an answer. This pitfall is [being discussed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186954/allow-anyone-to-comment-but-hide-low-rep-users-comments-until-reviewed).

Comment: For the time being, I suggest making your answer more appropriate by including *why* it is you think it can't be changed. The number of hours/places you searched for how to disable the dropdown or the amount of experience you have with the IDE would serve as a good metric for the likelihood that your conjecture is correct.

Comment: @dbudzins Thanks for looking it up, but I'm not sure if the name is "Context Switcher" as it implies in the blog post. It may be so for an Univeral App, but for C#, as you can see from my picture and the tooltip, it's more of a "Project Switcher". But the entire bar is called the "Navigation Bar" as you also have found (took me awhile to find what it's called). I see that you can disable the entire bar, but I like the bar, just wish I can disable that part. Hope they will put out an update for that.

Comment: @Ionian316 It's referred to as the **Context Switcher** because it changes the Universal App _build_ _context_ in which the file you are looking at is to be evaluated and built (i.e. Windows 8.1, Windows Phone, etc.) The tooltip refers to projects because that's how the build context is determined, but as your initial post implied, talking about projects here is confusing.

Comment: FWIW, I think this answer is perfectly appropriate, regardless of whether it strictly qualifies as a "fact-based" answer.

Comment: The whole first sentence is not true anymore, you can disable the context switcher for all language or just for one. In fact, this answer could start by your 4th block

Answer (score 6):

A specific issue has been opened at:
http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/5748900-add-option-to-exclude-the-new-shared-file-dropdow
Please vote !

Comment: Thanks for opening the issue!

Answer (score 5):

In Visual Studio 2013 Update 3, which was released this week (http://www.visualstudio.com/news/2014-aug-4-vs) , we have added the ability to re-size the splitters in the Navigation Bar to your own taste. We will save this setting for you. This means if you don't want to use real-estate on the Context Switcher, you can make it very small, but without changing the keyboard behavior of the Navigation Bar. We hope you like this change, which will also appear in the next public release of Visual Studio "14".

Comment: Thanks for listening to our feedback and implementing this fix!

Comment: You're welcome! Let us know how you like the change - does it work well for you?

Comment: No it doesn't work well - it's extra clutter that I don't need. Please, could you add an option to hide the Context Switcher completely?

Comment: Hello @MarkWilson-ThomasMSFT, I am using VS 2013 update 4, I can re-size the splitters and they keep the change, but if I close and open the project again they get back to their default sizes. Is this expected? Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem as @RafaelMerlin: I can resize the drop downs but as soon as I close vs.net and reopen it and load a project, they're again as the default. This is on win8.1 32bit. On win8.1 64bit, I can't reproduce it. It's odd but VERY annoying.

Comment: No, that's not by design - it should remember the settings between Visual Studio restarts. Can you file a bug on https://connect.microsoft.com/visualStudio/ and we'll take a look at this?

Answer (score 3):

There is no (official anyway) way to hide the project dropdown currently. We are considering it though.

Please file a suggestion on http://visualstudio.uservoice.com or file a bug on https://connect.microsoft.com to get your feedback heard.