# Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 - C# navigation bar drop down menus not working

Tags: c#, ide, visual-studio-2013

In Visual Studio 2013 Update 2, my C# [navigation bar](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/06/03/using-the-navigation-bar-vstiptool0026.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20zainnab%20%28Visual%20Studio%20Tips%20and%20Tricks%29) isn't working when docked in the main VS window. The drop down menus don't open. I can scroll using the arrow keys when the menus have focus but can't navigate by typing a letter. When it isn't docked in the main VS window the menus work fine. I've uninstalled all extensions.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I have the same problem in that the dropdowns do not drop down. However, I only get this when VS is running on my second screen. If I run on my main screen, the dropdowns work fine. Are you using a dual screen system? If so, maybe drag VS on to the main screen and see if it fixes it for you.

Comment: Excellent that's it. And it explains they worked when undocked - I was dragging the code window to my main screen.

Comment: Try making the other monitor your "main monitor" under Windows Screen Resolution settings.  Fixed it on both monitors for me.

Comment: I added a connect issue with a pointer back to this question. 

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/874023/c-drop-downs-at-top-of-editor-dont-work-if-vs-net-2013-2-is-being-used-on-the-non-primary-monitor

Comment: This is now fixed in VS 2013 Update 3:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43721

Comment: I thought i was losing my mind! VS2013 Update 4 [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=44921)

Comment: I have Update 4 and I'm seeing the issue.  I only have one screen....sometimes if I hit Alt-F though,  the file menu eventually comes up.  This seems like a big bug.

Answer (score 46):

[Visual Studio editor dev here]

Yes, it's a bug we introduced in Update 2. Sorry about that, we are testing a fix right now.

This bug affects only monitors on the left side of the main monitor. So a workaround (as Paul suggested above) is to make the leftmost monitor the "Main display" (via Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display\Screen Resolution) and then there would be no affected monitors at all.

If that doesn't work for you for some reason, the other workaround is to drag Visual Studio (or floating document window) to the main monitor or any monitor on the right of the main one.

[Update] This is fixed in VS 2013 Update 3 CTP2 (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2933779/en-us).

Comment: If you could make this optional would also be great: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23659126/visual-studio-2013-update-2-remove-project-dropdown-in-c-sharp-navigation-bar

Comment: Also affected by this. Have 3 monitors, and the middle one was the main one - VS on the left most one got no working dropdowns for selecting members etc, but on the main one ok. swapping left to primary monitor sorts it too.

Comment: @Oleg - is there a separate hotfix now available to fix this?

Comment: "This bug affects only monitors on the left side of the main monitor." - initially I thought you were joking, but I just tested it and it's true. That's hilarious! Thanks for fixing it :-)

Comment: link to the download seems broken :/

Answer (score 4):

I've also got the issue.  And yep, using a dual screen setup.  If I right click on the desktop and go to Screen Resolution and make the other monitor my "main monitor" it fixes it.  Bizarre!!

Answer (score 2):

I installed the latest VS 2013 Update 3 CTP and it fixed the problem for me:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2933779/en-us

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the drop down control was minimized. I just had to drag it to resize again.