# Method list dropdown no longer functional

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

The method list dropdown, as well as the project and class view drop down boxes are no longer working within the editor window with VS2013 update 2.

I suspect that this issue began after the update, but I cannot be certain ( I didn't pay much attention to it until this morning, although I performed the update when it was released)

For example, I expect VS to look like like [image: vs method list]

(from the screenshot posted in [the accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819519/visual-studio-window-which-shows-list-of-methods) however it looks like:

[image: method list dropdown box not working]

I've tried the following:

- Run as administrator and regular user
- Remove and readd the toolbar via Option -> Text Editor -> C# -> Navigation Bar

I've also noted that

- issue occurs across all files
- it affects all parts of the navigation bar
- The dropdown's do update to reflect the current position of the editor

Any ideas on how I can resolve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 - C# navigation bar drop down menus not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23676285/visual-studio-2013-update-2-c-sharp-navigation-bar-drop-down-menus-not-working)

Comment: This seems to only occur on secondary monitors to the left of the main monitor. http://stackoverflow.com/q/23676285/65611 and https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/874023

Comment: @JoelPotter Thanks - I was unable to find that question when I originally posted this one