# Navigation bar (events bar) in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

In the last years I used VS with VB .NET.
There was a event-bar on the top of the code window. In C# I don't see that bar. On the left I can see my project, in the middle I can see the class name and on the right I can see all my methods and functions.

In VB .NET I had my project, the list of controls and on the right the events which the controls provide.

**The navigation in VB .NET look like this**
[image]

**The navigation in C# look like this**
[image]

I want the same navigation in C#, is that possible?

Comment: I see that bar on screenshot. What is the problem?

Comment: I imagine you can configure the interface to looks like what you are used to, but it is a good idea to adapt, it will pay in the long run.

Comment: If your question is why are there **three** dropdowns, then you can resize the "Context Switcher" dropdown - the left-most one - down to the minimum size, but you can't (I believe) get rid of it. - [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23659126/visual-studio-2013-update-2-remove-project-dropdown-in-c-sharp-navigation-bar)

Comment: Sorry this picture is misunderstanding. This isn't my VS, but it looked the exact same, but now in VS + C#  projects it doesnt look like this...

Comment: How does your project looks like? Open any cs-file in any project and make a screenshot.

Comment: What panel do you want to see?, Project explorer, buttons event or what? Can you upload an image with an example in visual basic please?

Comment: added screenshots to my question, hope this helps